# How to serialize file to bytes or other java structure and send it in RPC

Tags: java, file, serialization, tcp, zeromq

I need to read a file, for example "test.sh" or "test.cmd", that contains simple scripts.

Using Java I need to serialize that and send it via TCP/IP (using JAXB + ZeroMQ) to an other node in the network via TCP/IP.

What is the best way to just take the file and serialize it to bytes, and then convert it back to a file on the other side (the node that received the serialized bytes)?

Answer (score 3):

Assuming the files are small enough to fit into memory without any issues, the `InputStream.read(byte[] b, int off, int len)` method is probably what you're looking for. This method reads at most `len` bytes of data from the input stream into byte array `b` at the specified offset `off` and returns the actual number of bytes read. The method gives no guarantees only guarantees that at least one byte will be read as long as the end of the file hasn't been reached and there are no errors, so you will have to call this method in a loop and check the return value in order to update the offset for subsequent calls.

Writing the data back to a file is then as simple as calling `OutputStream.write(byte[] b)`.